# Sales counts by week for individual items sold

Tags: sql

I have a large SQL table that contains, among other fields, the following

```
Item,              Date Sold,
1 Day Coaster      2014-11-10,
3 Day Coaster      2014-02-16,
1 Day Coaster      2014-11-11,
AC-Zip             2014-12-21,
5 Day Package      2014-05-15,
1 Day Coaster      2014-11-07,
```

Being new to SQL, my expertise can only select the items individually and take the counts from individual results and type them into excel from the rows affected result.

I need to be able to pull the count of individual items sold by week and list the counts by week into an excel spreadsheet thus;

```
Week                          Item                   Count
2014-11-07-2014-11-13       1 Day Coaster            3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Group BY statement.

here is a sample SQLFiddle, it might get you started: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/442fda/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
SELECT A.Item,A.DateRange,COUNT(A.Item) 
FROM (
SELECT Item,
(SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min(Date_Sold)), Min(Date_Sold))) < YEAR(Min(Date_Sold))
        THEN
        CAST(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR, 0 ,GETDATE())), 0) AS Varchar(50))  
        + ' TO ' + Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min(Date_Sold))), Min(Date_Sold))  AS Varchar(50))
        ELSE
        Cast(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min(Date_Sold)), Min(Date_Sold)) AS Varchar(50)) 
        + ' TO ' +     Cast(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min(Date_Sold))), Min(Date_Sold))  AS Varchar(50))
    END AS  DateRange
FROM <YOUR_TABLE> B
WHERE A.Date_Sold=B.Date_Sold
AND A.Item=B.Item
group by Item
) AS DateRange
FROM <YOUR_TABLE> A
) A 
GROUP BY Item,DateRange;
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking at.

Answer (score -1):

USe this. [**Fiddler Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41550a/1)

**Output:**

[image]

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE weekdays
(
  datevalue datetime NOT NULL
  , Item VARCHAR(MAX)
  );

INSERT INTO weekdays (datevalue, item) VALUES
  ('2014-11-10', '1 Day Coaster'),
  ('2014-02-16', '2 Day Coaster'),
  ('2014-11-11', '1 Day Coaster'),
  ('2014-12-21', 'AC-Zip'),
  ('2014-05-15', '5 Day Package'),
  ('2014-11-07', '1 Day Coaster');


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_GetFirstDayOfWeek]
( @pInputDate    DATETIME )
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN

SET @pInputDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @pInputDate, 111)
RETURN DATEADD(DD, 1 - DATEPART(DW, @pInputDate),
               @pInputDate)

END
GO

SET DATEFIRST 5

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.Date, 101) + ' - ' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(d, 6, A.Date), 101) AS Week,
      A.Item, 
      COUNT(A.Item) AS COUNT FROM
(SELECT [dbo].ufn_GetFirstDayOfWeek(datevalue) AS Date, item FROM weekdays) AS A
GROUP BY A.Date, A.Item
```